# Hide/Secure API authentication Call/Method in react-native from reverse engineering/any other generic hack

Tags: react-native, cordova, security

I would like to know how to secure the API authentication call/method in React-Native from reverse engineering. Because I have the method to make a header value that goes with the authentication call and gets verified on server. But I don't know how to secure it.

There is no OAuth method implemented on server, while the previous app is build in Cordova, in which they made the function in native android and access it through Cordova, and I can't find such a way to do that in RN

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like react-native-secure-storage or react-native-keychain to safely store your api keys in local storage.

https://github.com/oyyq99999/react-native-secure-storage#readme
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain

If the server has properly implemented OAuth, you don't need to worry about reverse engineering.

The personal or client access token that you send with each request can easily be revoked on any kind of misuse.

Comment: Updated my question.